# Javascript: Any workarounds for getting Chrome for Android to fire off touchmove and touchend event listeners other than using event.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, events

When using event listeners with the touchmove and touchend events, I can't get Chrome for Android to acknowledge those events unless I first use event.preventDefault(); earlier in the code. If I'm not wanting to block the default scroll functionality, is there any other workaround I can use to get Chrome for Android to acknowledge these events?

Sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Bind touch event listeners.
var elem = $('html').get(0);
elem.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) { console.info('"touchstart" detected. Coordinates - ' + getCoord(e)); });
elem.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { console.info('"touchmove" detected. Coordinates - ' + getCoord(e)); });
elem.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) { console.info('"touchend" detected. Coordinates - ' + getCoord(e)); });

function getCoord(e) {
var touch = false;
if (e.touches.length > 0) {
touch = e.touches[0];
} else {
touch = e.changedTouches[0];
}
if (touch) {
return 'x: ' + touch.pageX + ', y: ' + touch.pageY;
}
}
```

Example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jQ2VS/1/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google Chrome will fire a `touchcancel` event about 200 milliseconds after `touchstart` if it thinks the user is panning/scrolling and you do not call `event.preventDefault()`.

Assuming that you want to intercept horizontal touch events and let vertical touch events cause panning/scrolling, a workaround would be:

1. On `touchstart`, store the coordinates in a variable, and set `iteration` to 0.
2. For each `touchmove` event, set `iteration` to `iteration`+1.
3. When `iteration` is equal to 4 (just a "magic number" I found to be reliable on my set-up), calculate the total touch offset deltas for x- and y- axes.
   EDIT: on mobile devices you'll only receive one touchmove without event.preventDefault()
4. If x-axis offset > y-axis offset * 3 then fire event.preventDefault(). (This ensures the the gesture is pretty much horizontal)

The down-side for this is that user can only either swipe left/right or scroll up/down.

Comment: But the touchmove also fires only once or twice and then stops even though the finger is still moving on the screen

Comment: I found the magic value to be 4 on desktop, and 1 only mobile.  If you're targeting mobile only, then you might as well event.preventDefault() on the first touchmove if the touch deltas are heavily horizontal.  This is also the behavior observed for Android's GMail App Drawer: once you start swiping, you can't scroll, and when you scroll, you can't swipe open/close the drawer.

Comment: Great, just hit same issue yesterday. For now Firefox didn't apply this rule. Maybe I should look into html spec to see which one is follow spec

Comment: if you're working with webview, you need preventDefault in onTouchStartCapture, I spent one week to find the `capture`...

Answer (score 7):

Finally I found the solution (pure js) even in case you might want use it for swipe:

```
var swipe = function() {

    var touchX, touchY, movX, movY, go;

    function prevent(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    function start(e) {
        go = false;
        document.addEventListener("touchmove", prevent, false);
        touchX = e.touches[0].pageX;
        touchY = e.touches[0].pageY;
    }

    function move(e) {
        movX = e.touches[0].pageX - touchX;
        movY = e.touches[0].pageY - touchY;
        if(!go) {
            (Math.abs(movY) < Math.abs(movX)) ? go = true : stop(e);
        } else {
            /* *************** */
            // cast your spell
            /* *************** */
        }
    }

    function stop(e) {
        document.removeEventListener("touchmove", prevent, false);
    }

    document.addEventListener("touchstart", start, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", move, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", stop, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchleave", stop, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchcancel", stop, true);

}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that you have to preventDefault on the first touchmove event otherwise they will be cancelled.

Comment: I'm aware that preventDefault would help. As I asked above, though, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use preventDefault, because I don't want to break scroll functionality in this case.

Comment: I know. But the answer is you have to prevent default :/ if you want to get all touch events on the html element.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all. It's not a 'simple answer'. It's a recommendation to give up looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that preventing the touchcancel worked fine.

Comment: If you have an example that worked well for you, please consider posting some code to help support your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct.

On Android if preventDefault is not set on touchstart the device assumes native scrolling and no more touch events are sent to webview.  If preventDefault is set all native scrolling is disabled.

There is a shim to provide swipe events with native scrolling here : https://github.com/TNT-RoX/android-swipe-shim